# How in PhpStorm 2020 to keep and run some commands?

Tags: phpstorm

If there is a way in PhpStorm 2020 to keep some commands and by short key to select
one of commands and run it in internal console ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you please provide an example or two of such commands? It looks like this can be done in a couple of ways, but I need more details: a lot of tools are context/environment depended.

Comment: As I work in laravel I need periodically clear cache : php artisan config:cache
php artisan route:cache  and see output that did not raise errors

Comment: You can configure artisan as a tool and invoke it pressing ctrl twice: https://i.gyazo.com/7da8a35e6eb5e7e808ca7a5f7c9a29d5.png. Then use code completion to find the required ones: https://i.gyazo.com/e047a55dc2f6981350021d5622e13b64.png. The window also stores recent commands: https://i.gyazo.com/49e0240b61cc6d56d1927d5b55a14710.png

Comment: Trying to add Command line tool support : https://imgur.com/a/bh6bEAN
I do not see laravel option in selection. Is it some misconfiguring in my IDE/project?

Comment: Looks like you're on an old IDE version. Try following these instructions then: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2020.1/laravel.html#use_artisan_cli

Comment: Thanks! Also if there is a way to run custom linux commands file in the app root?

Comment: Yes, you can configure one at File | Settings | Tools | External Tools.

Comment: Thanks!
I create such commmand : https://imgur.com/a/3Qe9XIV
actually that is linux batch running 6-7 clear cach, config, route etc commands
But when I open “Run Any” with doubled CTRL I do not see “cc” command : https://imgur.com/a/goJnK7z
Wan it configured incorectly ?

Comment: Oh, that's a shame. Apparently, external tools are not included in "Run anything", sorry :( You can run them following ways: 1) via Tools > External Tools; 2) via Search everywhere (double tap shift) 3) via Find Action (ctrl+shift+A)

Comment: Sorry I did not find points 2 and 3. have my PhpStorm 2020.1 them ? Where have I to search these commands ?

Comment: Strange, you should be able to, even in 2020.1. Here's search everywhere: https://i.gyazo.com/c25ae0d6006f49275e5318e6159986af.png, here's Find Action: https://i.gyazo.com/6b9d872db2a3d49bed027ea18d25e03d.png

Comment: How to open search everywhere dialog?

Comment: Hit `shift` twice. Or Ctrl+Shift+A (Help > Find Action) > type `Search everywhere`